# Long action and waiting for a new view in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, loading

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3. In the view, I have a link in view that initiates a new request:

```
@Html.ActionLink ("Link", "LongAction", "Home")
```

The action "LongAction" takes a long time, and while waiting for the new view I want show an image that simulates loading a whole new view:

```
public ActionResult LongAction()
{
Threas.Sleep(10000);
return View();
}
```

Comment: You need to look into asynchronicity then. You can fire a ajax task and display a loader while waiting for the action to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. User Clicks button
2. Show a loading GIF
3. POST/GET to a server endpoint
4. Server endpoint kicks of the long running task.
5. On the complete event of the ajax request hide the loader.
6. Notify user

You can look into binding it together with Jquery, or if you want to use something in the mvc framework you can look at the [Ajax ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Either way you can hide/show the loader with javascript.

JQuery Example:

```
$('#userButton').click(function(){
    longRunningTask();
    return false;
});

function longRunningTask()
{
     $('#loader').show();
     $.ajax({ 
        url: 'http://serverendpointaddress.co.uk'
     }).done(function(){
        //notify the user
     }).always(function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
     });
}
```